# Return Table Rows in a Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCustomers
(
  @ZIPCode VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE

AS BEGIN
SELECT * dbo.GetCustomers
WHERE dbo.GetCustomers.ZIPCODE = ZIPCode 
RETURN
END
```

Im not familar with the syntax. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would have been worth guessing that the parameter `@ZIPCode` would go into the query as `@ZIPCode`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCustomers
(
  @ZIPCode VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE

AS
RETURN (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers
    WHERE dbo.Customers.ZIPCODE = @ZIPCode
    )
END
```

Your first attempt `WHERE dbo.Customers.ZIPCODE = ZIPCode` is the same as `WHERE dbo.Customers.ZIPCODE = dbo.CustomersZIPCode`. That is, return all rows

Comment: Would have been helpful to point out what you changed, i.e. `ZIPCode` -> `@ZIPCode`.

Comment: @gbr im making a regex search pattern and compare it against it. but my only problem is to retrun it. i will change it on my code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCustomers ( 
@ZIPCode VARCHAR(255) 
) 
RETURNS TABLE  
AS return (SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers WHERE dbo.Customers.ZIPCODE = @ZIPCode)
```

Comment: there is a reason why give the function a body. there is some code. i need just to know how to make something like this RETURNS TABLE   AS dbo.Customers

Comment: @noname: this is an "inline table valued function" and only needs a RETURN. No BEGIN+END body.

Comment: @gbn thanks for reply but there are code in my body. i do something with the ZIPCode var before i compare it with dbo.Customers. You cant see it in my post.

Comment: @noname: we have answered the question you gave.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any good reason to create a function to do this when a normal Stored Procedure will do the trick.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomers
@ZIPCode VARCHAR(255)

AS

SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE Customers.ZIPCODE = @ZIPCode
```

Comment: True, no obvious reason to do so.